# Python: How to define a variable named 'class' inside of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

Im using flask with sqlalchemy.

I have a Model that is defined as such:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer)
    class = Column(Text) #Can I do this? I need a field named 'class'.
```

If not, then how can I define variables in python that are the same as keywords?

Comment: You cannot do this, because `class` is a reserved word. You can name it `class_` if you want, that's what , e.g.,`beautifulSoup` does.

Comment: `klass` is an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying

```
class_ = Column('class', Text)
```

will give you an orm field known as "class_" corresponding to a column in your database named "class". It sounds like this may be what you are trying to do.

It may or may not be the best thing to do. You may be better off doing something like

```
clas = Column(Text)
```

and intentionally spelling it "funny", just to keep things simpler in the long run. SQLAlchemy is really happiest when the orm names are the same as the column names.

(Does this address your question?)

Comment: (porque downvotar?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a variable with then name *class*, as class is a reserved keyword.

https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html

> 2.3.1 Keywords
>
> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of
>   the language, a**nd cannot be used as ordinary identifiers**. They must be
>   spelled exactly as written here:
>
> and       del       from      not       while     as        elif
>   global    or        with      assert    else      if        pass
>   yield     break     except    import    print               **class**
>   exec      in        raise               continue  finally   is
>   return              def       for       lambda    try

**If not then how can I define variables in python that are the same as keywords?**

As suggested in the comments you can append a character (e.g. `_`) after the word, and that will compile fine.

Answer (score -1):

'class' is a protected word in Python, pretty much meaning that you can't overwrite it. If you want to have something similar to 'class', as a variable, then I suggest using 'Class' or 'class_(class name/topic)' to overcome your issue.